# I am get error as ClassCastException in below code

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

i am new to java and i am learning deserialization and while doing so i am getting classcastexception

I did serialization at one class and deserialization at another

serialization

```
zipfile f = new zipfile(30,"kavin");

ArrayList<zipfile> a = new ArrayList<zipfile>(101);
a.add(f);

String file = "def.txt";
try {
    FileOutputStream fi = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(fi);

    s.writeObject(f);
    System.out.println(f.age);
    s.close();
    fi.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

deserialization

```
String file = "def.txt";


try {
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
    f=(deserialization)s.readObject();
    System.out.println(f.age);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

output

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: demo2.zipfile cannot be cast to demo2.deserialization
    at demo2.deserialization.main(deserialization.java:69)

Comment: Post your code along with error on console.

Comment: `f = (deserialization)s.readObject();` is obviously not possible. `f` is a `zipfile` (lower case type?) and cannot be cast to `deserialization` (again, lower case?).

Comment: You read an object from your file which contains a serialized `zipfile`. And then you cast it to `deserialization`. Why do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following must be kept in mind when dealing with Serialization:

1. If a parent class has implemented Serializable interface then child class doesn’t need to implement it but vice-versa is not true.
2. Only non-static data members are saved via Serialization process.
3. Static data members and transient data members are not saved via Serialization process. So, if you don’t want to save the value of a non-static data member then make it transient.
4. The constructor of the object is never called when an object is deserialized.
5. Associated objects must be implementing the Serializable interface.

Try to look thru your code and find if one of the above-mentioned cases is the problem.

For more help, refer to the source at - [Serialization in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/)